# Extra padding in custom actionbar view

Tags: android

Using the new Theme.Material, how do I remove this extra padding in my custom actionbar view?

**My custom actionbar layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="horizontal" android:background="#ff640000">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/actionbar_button_menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="menu" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/actionbar_textview_statustext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Test"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/actionbar_button_add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="add" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**My Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.custom_actionbar);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    }
}
```

[image: problem]

Comment: Could you post more info? Your style file and layout

Comment: Nothing out of the ordinary, probably just a flag I need, but can't really figure out what it is.

Comment: There's a tool called "hierarchy viewer". In AndroidStudio go to 'Tools/Android/Android Device Monitor' and open 'Hierarchy View' perspective there. This tool often helps to find that kind of issues. Also i see you're trying to implement iOS-on-Android antipattern. Please, read about what not to do on android here http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html